# Symfony 2.2 - upload files

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I am new in SYmfony and going to make a blog service with symfony2. I want to let user upload a picture and show it On his/her post. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use [dustin10/VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle).

Instructions on how to use the bundle can be found in the [documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).

Further information can be found in the cookbook chapter [How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) but VichUploaderBundle is the easiest way to get you started.

For image processing have a look at [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle).